# Add a user without administrator rights?

Tags: ubuntu

I have a server with Ubuntu system .I would add a user named "newland" user but not grant administrator rights.

how can I get？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add user by using the 'adduser' command.

```
sudo adduser newland
```

Comment: Thank you for answer ! This way can add a user ,but  he can range other directories 。likes  “/home/hello”.